# Chrome developer tools not showing pseudoelements

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, pseudo-element

I use Chrome's Developer Tools a lot and on the whole I prefer it to Firebug, but one thing that I've been noticing lately is that sometimes it fails to show my pseudoelements in the styles area.  Sometimes it does, so I know it works occasionally, but some, seemingly, random times it doesn't.  The obvious response to that would be "are you sure they are set up properly?" Which I consider each and every time it happens.  But the elements are visible in the template, they just don't show up in the styles so I can't edit them.

I'm referring to :before and :after mainly because thats what I use the most.

Has anyone else had this problem?  If you haven't, I'm sure this will be hard to answer, but I'll supply any more information I can.  I would show you the example where I'm having trouble but it's on a private server.

Comment: Make a fiddle so we can take a look.

Comment: Sounds like https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=143326, which should be fixed in Chrome 24.